# Audits doesn't take into consideration the filter

Tags: bug, review-audits

I was reviewing "First Posts" queue with "answers" filter, and a wild question appeared:

[image]

This way is very easy to detect some audits.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but aren't audits supposed to be obvious?

Comment: @Stijn That's too obious, I think

Comment: @SysDragon: you'd be surprised how many people fail what you would consider "obvious" audits (though the line between dodgy review audits and sheer stupidity is more blurred than you think).

Comment: @SysDragon Qantas is exactly right.  Audits are not meant to be educational tools.  While they can help teach how to judge posts, they are really designed to only look legit enough so someone who is not paying attention will not blindly click "Looks Good" or "No Action Needed" or some other robotic action.  In the end, if you are paying attention to enough to notice the tags are not applicable, then you passed.