# Low quality review audits should take question/answer filter mode into account

Tags: feature-request, review, review-audits, low-quality-posts

In some review queues like <s>First Posts or</s> Low Quality Posts, there is the ability to set a filter by the post type: question or answer. In case of audit there can be a wrong post type for review. For instance, I chose only questions, but I see answer for review:

> [image: qa]

And the opposite:

> [image: aq]

A similar bug was [fixed on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289627/why-does-the-low-quality-posts-review-queue-still-have-question-audits), where the Low Quality Posts queue is always filtered only to answers for everyone but question audits were appearing; it should be implemented on other sites too.

This was already reported at [Audits doesn't take into consideration the filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208172/audits-doesnt-take-into-consideration-the-filter), but that was closed as a duplicate of a more general request about filters (including tag filters), which was marked as by design because filtering via *tags* would be difficult. However, it is *much* easier to filter answers and questions, as demonstrated by the above Stack Overflow bug fix.

Currently, one can accidentally take the wrong action if they've applied such a filter but the wrong type of post appears (e.g. negatively review a known-good question audit that they thought was a non-answer since they filtered only to answers, or positively review a known-bad answer audit that was a non-answer but they thought was a new question since they filtered only to questions).

Can this please be implemented?

**Update:** Per Catija's comment, as the First Posts queue was split into separate queues for questions and answers, this is no longer an issue for that queue. However, this still **continues to be an issue** on the low quality review queue on sites other than those where Triage is enabled. Can this please be fixed there?

Comment: This is especially applicable if you've opted to review only answers but see a question audit; you might fail the audit because you think it's a non-answer.

Comment: Looks like this bug has [already been reported a long time ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208172/audits-doesnt-take-into-consideration-the-filter), but it was closed as a duplicate of a more general post that was marked as by design. You don't mind if I edit this into a feature request, so that this isn't a duplicate?

Comment: With the release of two queues for First questions and First answers, this is arguably "fixed" for the queue you mention here.

Comment: @Catija The post here mentioned the low quality review queue; it still continues to be an issue here, so I hope this wasn't removed from SE's internal tracker for this reason.

Comment: I'm not sure why is that a problem at all. The audits are meant to test if you're paying attention while reviewing. What better tests that if not putting something that shouldn't be there? In other words, if someone fails that audit, they are ***really*** not paying attention and that makes it a good audit in a way...

Comment: @Tomerikoo As stated, if one's filtered to answers and a question audit appears, they may review the post text, think it was posted as an answer, review it for deletion as a non-answer, and fail the audit despite having paid attention. This actually used to also be an issue on sites with Triage enabled, on which the LQ queue was always filtered to answers for everyone but question audits appeared, but was fixed there, so the fix should be easy here.