# Review audits are not working in sync with filter in First posts review queue

Tags: support, review, review-audits

I was in the First posts review queue reviewing posts. I noticed this suddenly:

[image: Screenshot of the First posts review queue: https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/1163303]

Link: https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/1163303

As you can see in the screenshot, I have used the filter option to only see questions. But I was asked to review a review audit which was an answer.

According to logic, when I have turned the filter on for only questions, only review audits which are questions should be shown; review audits which are answers should not be shown.

Comment: Feature request asking for this to be changed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324050/review-audits-should-take-question-answer-filter-mode-into-account

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a filter, and notice that this one doesn't match the filter, you're not who the review audit is targeting.

Review audits are meant to be extremely easy to spot. They're designed to trip up the robo-reviewers who aren't paying the slightest bit of attention to the post and are just reviewing for the badges. You've noticed that this is an audit? Great! It means you were paying attention. Well done. You're not the target for the audits.

Comment: When it comes to certain types of this (e.g. tag filters), I agree with this, but when it comes to the specific type in the question (question vs. answer filters), I do think it should be fixed. Users who've filtered to answers may expect to only see answers, so when they come across an audit question they may think it's a non-answer and fail the audit. Same goes if they've filtered to and are expecting only questions: they may fail the audit if it reads like a valid question but was actually posted as a non-answer.

Comment: This was actually fixed on Stack Overflow: its LQ queue is filtered to answers for everyone, but for a time, question audits were appearing in the queue, but this was fixed so only answer audits would appear. Based on that, I think it's technically easier to implement on the other sites too.

Comment: Mithical, I initially thought that it was a real review, not an audit, and thought that this was a bug  https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19693